# How to add class dynamic using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

> See code below:

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(".main-div").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.main-div.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe1</div>

<div class="main-div">Div1</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe2</div>

<div class="main-div">Div2</div>
</div>
```

> Hi guys, can you help me with this matter? Well my goal is to when I
> click the first button it should only add class on the first `.main-div`
> however, by using toggle it adds also on the second div. Can anyone
> help me how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
    $(this).next(".main-div").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.main-div.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe1</div>

<div class="main-div">Div1</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe2</div>

<div class="main-div">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Your problem is the `$(".main-div").toggleClass("active");` selects every `.main-div`, not just the sibling element.

The easiest way to select the next sibling with the `.main-div` class is `$(this).next(".main-div").toggleClass("active");`

You can read more about jQuery selectors at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: thanks for this idea I'll look into it now :)

Comment: hi thanks for this idea however using `.next` is only working if you have 2 div's on your `.main-div`. What if you have many? Thanks

Comment: It should work for as many blocks with`.main-div` as you want, assuming you keep that same structure with a single `.main-div` per parent `.one` div.

If you want to use multiple `.main-div` in the same parent then you can use `$(this).parent().children(".main-div").toggleClass("active");`, however it will highlight all the `.main-div` in that parent